# How to change the values of columns in a big dataframe using the names of variables?

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns, substitution

I have this dataset (but let's suppose it is very big with many rows and columns)

```
df = data.frame(x = c(1,0,0,1),
                y = c(0,0,1,1))
```

I wish to use the names of variables x, y,  etc.. every time while substuting 1 and 0 with *yes* and *no* as follows :

```
df = data.frame(x = c('yes_x','no_x','no_x','yes_x'),
                y = c('no_y','no_y','yes_y','yes_y'))
```

would appreciate the halp. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `dplyr`, with `cur_column`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(x:y, 
                ~ ifelse(.x == 1, "yes", "no") %>% 
                  paste(cur_column(), sep = "_")))
```

---

In base R, with `mapply`:

```r
df[] <- ifelse(df == 1, "yes", "no")
df[] <- mapply(paste, df, colnames(df), sep = "_")
```

output

```r
      x     y
1 yes_x  no_y
2  no_x  no_y
3  no_x yes_y
4 yes_x yes_y
```

Answer (score 2):

A data.table approach may be useful for you if you have a large dataset:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
for(k in names(df)) set(df,j=k,value = paste0(fifelse(df[[k]]==1,"yes_","no_"),k))
```

Output:

```
        x      y
   <char> <char>
1:  yes_x   no_y
2:   no_x   no_y
3:   no_x  yes_y
4:  yes_x  yes_y
```